# Obtaining the household median income from ACS data

Tags: r, tidycensus

The code below perfectly returns what I need: the household median income for each puma using 2019 ACS (1-year). However, what is missing is the States name. I tried the option of state="all" but it did not work. How can I obtain my data of interest by states and puma?

Thanks,

NM

```
PUMA_level <- get_acs(geography = "puma",
                                         variable = "B19013_001",
                                         survey = "acs1",
                                        # state="all",
                                         year = 2019)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `usmap::fips_info` function you could get a list of state codes, names and abbreviations which you could then merge to your census data like so:

```r
library(tidycensus)
library(usmap)

PUMA_level <- get_acs(geography = "puma",
                      variable = "B19013_001",
                      survey = "acs1",
                      year = 2019,
                      keep_geo_vars = TRUE)
#> Getting data from the 2019 1-year ACS
#> The 1-year ACS provides data for geographies with populations of 65,000 and greater.

PUMA_level$fips <- substr(PUMA_level$GEOID, 1, 2)

states <- usmap::fips_info(unique(PUMA_level$fips))
#> Warning in get_fips_info(fips_, sortAndRemoveDuplicates): FIPS code(s) 72 not
#> found

PUMA_level <- merge(PUMA_level, states, by = "fips")

head(PUMA_level)
#>   fips   GEOID
#> 1   01 0100100
#> 2   01 0100200
#> 3   01 0100302
#> 4   01 0100400
#> 5   01 0100500
#> 6   01 0100301
#>                                                                                         NAME
#> 1                  Lauderdale, Colbert, Franklin & Marion (Northeast) Counties PUMA; Alabama
#> 2 Limestone & Madison (Outer) Counties--Huntsville City (Far West & Southwest) PUMA, Alabama
#> 3                                            Huntsville City (Central & South) PUMA, Alabama
#> 4                                                    DeKalb & Jackson Counties PUMA, Alabama
#> 5     Marshall & Madison (Southeast) Counties--Huntsville City (Far Southeast) PUMA, Alabama
#> 6                                   Huntsville (North) & Madison (East) Cities PUMA, Alabama
#>     variable estimate  moe abbr    full
#> 1 B19013_001    46449 3081   AL Alabama
#> 2 B19013_001    74518 6371   AL Alabama
#> 3 B19013_001    51884 5513   AL Alabama
#> 4 B19013_001    43406 3557   AL Alabama
#> 5 B19013_001    56276 3216   AL Alabama
#> 6 B19013_001    63997 5816   AL Alabama
```